# How to get windows logged on user name in Sitecore 9.2 application

Tags: authentication

I need to get the windows logged on user name in the Sitecore 9.2 application.

I have enabled windows authentication in IIS ,

and tried with the

**HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name**   its always giving me **"extranet\anonymous"**

And tried with **System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name** and **HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name**  but no luck.

Need help here to get the windows logged on user name

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve here but did you try by disabling the `anonymous user` and `Forms authentication`?

Comment: I want to get he windows logged on user name on page load. I need anonymous user in User Manager, so havnet disabled that user. But disbaled the forms authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in Sitecore 9.2, the “LOGON_USER” returns empty.

Furthermore, when you try to get the windows identity username through the `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` it’s return the Anonymous User, or the application Poll identity name. It will not give you the User that it’s logged in the computer or VM.

The only way to have Windows authentication is to disabled the Sitecore Identity.

More details here: https://medium.com/@jalves_654/enabling-windows-authentication-sitecore-9-2-cfa25705b860

Comment: Thanks @andrei.